# Reactjs: Switch tab on click of button in component

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I have 2 tabs which both have same component.

On click of button in tab1 , tab2 should be selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/rzv6Lrjh/93/

In this fiddle

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
        <Tabs selected={0}>
          <Pane label="Tab 1">

            <Tickets key='1'/>
          </Pane>
          <Pane label="Tab 2">
            <Tickets key='2'/>
          </Pane>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: Hold some state in this component that determines which tab should be presented in the UI. In the render function just render the tab accordingly

Comment: @KeithAlpichi can you please provide code snippet

Answer (score 0):

As explained by keith Hold some state in this component and render the tab according to the states defined for the each tab

`this.state=

```
        this.statetab = {
    index: 1,
    fixedIndex: 1,
    inverseIndex: 0
  };

  handleFixedTabChange(index){
  alert(index)
    this.setState({fixedIndex: index});
  };

  handleInverseTabChange(index){
    this.setState({inverseIndex: index});
  };


const Tabb = () =>
(
 <section>
        <Tabs {...this.props} index={this.statetab.index} onChange={this.handleTabChange.bind(this)}>
          <Tab label='Primary'><small>Primary content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Secondary' onActive={this.handleActive.bind(this)}><small>Secondary content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Third' disabled><small>Disabled content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Fourth' hidden><small>Fourth content hidden</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Fifth'><small>Fifth content</small></Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <h5>Fixed Tabs</h5>
        <Tabs index={this.statetab.fixedIndex} onChange={this.handleFixedTabChange.bind(this)} fixed>
          <Tab label='First'><small>First Content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Second'><small>Second Content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Third'><small>Third Content</small></Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <h5>Inverse Tabs</h5>
        <Tabs index={this.statetab.inverseIndex} onChange={this.handleInverseTabChange.bind(this)} inverse>
          <Tab label='First'><small>First Content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Second'><small>Second Content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Third'><small>Third Content</small></Tab>
          <Tab label='Disabled' disabled><small>Disabled Content</small></Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </section>

);
```